# Sufficient Statistic for Uniform

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, sufficient-statistics

Let $X$ have the pdf $f_X (x;\theta)=1/(2\theta)$ for $-\theta<x<\theta$, zero elsewhere where $\theta>0$ Is the statistic $Y=|X|$ a sufficient statistic for $\theta$?

---

My book claims it is but I do not see it. A transformation argument shows that the distribution of $|X|$ is uniform with $f_X (x;\theta)=1/\theta$ for $0<x<\theta$. Thus the conditional probability

$$\frac{f(x_1;\theta)f(x_2;\theta)\ldots f(x_n;\theta)}{f_{|X|}(|X|;\theta)}$$

*does* depend on $\theta$ and therefore, $|X|$ cannot be a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: Use the Factorization Theorem...and don't forget the indicator function in the density when you do.

Comment: @cardinal I didn't use the Factorization for fear I might make a mistake with the indicator functions. Still, those two methods ought to agree right?

Comment: Yes, and they do! Let $T = |X|$. What is the *conditional* distribution of $X$ given $T$? Does it involve $\theta$? (And, fear not the power and simplicity of the factorization theorem.) :-)

Comment: @cardinal Conditional distribution of $X$ given $T$? It is supposed to be the joint distribution of all $X_i$ in the numerator, isn't it? See the fraction above. And then the fraction is $\frac{1/(2\theta)^n}{1/ \theta}$

Comment: @cardinal A statistic $Y=u (X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$  is said to be sufficient iff the conditional distribution of $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ given $Y=y$ does not depend on $\theta$. Have I misunderstood it?

Comment: JohnK, I think the only misunderstanding is that the question is only asking about the situation where the sample size is $n=1$.

Comment: @cardinal Oh right. That explains it. So simple lol. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider typing up and posting an answer to your own question here. We'll be happy to help work out any remaining kinks. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that the sample size is just 1 here. So the conditional density becomees:

$$\frac{1/2\theta}{1/\theta}=1/2$$ and as required does not depend on $\theta$. Also, by the factorization theorem:

$$\frac{1}{2\theta} I_{\{-\theta,\theta\}}\left(x \right)=\frac{1}{2\theta} I_{\{0,\theta\}} \left(|x| \right)$$

and therefore $|x|$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.